# Laravel4 index method

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

I want to create a resource controller (REST) for "events" (organised events).
"Events" are the resource.

I need two methods:

- Get events based on a query parameter (autofill search box in the front end);
- Get all events within the bounds of a map location.

Both methods seem good candidates to use the index() method.
I was thinking to use the index method for the second case, and make a separate callable method for the first case (the query search).

How would you structure this specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are ways to return a subset of 'all events', why not make them both separate URL parameters for the same index method? `/events?search=xyz&location=xyz`, for example.

If the filters were separate in the index action, it would also allow you to filter events by location *and* a user search (with a query string similar to the one above), which might be a nice feature in the future.

Comment: True. Creating both filters on the same index method actually seems the most obvious way to go, allowing me to combine as you say.